# How to implement all translations in one form with Mobility gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, mobility

In my Rails app i'm using [Mobility gem](https://github.com/shioyama/mobility) for translations

How to build a form with all translations, like:

- name [en]: _______
- name [fr]: ________
- name [de]: _______
- ...

What is the best way?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: You're asking about Mobility, you should at least mention that, and that (I assume) you're using it with Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Oldharlem/f6b1e9dcc79127039c9fab744327e2c5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not really any documentation about this, but it's not difficult to create a form like that with Mobility.

Here's an example, assuming you have an object `@post` with a translated attribute `title`:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <% I18n.available_locales.each do |locale| %>
    <div>
      <% attr_name = "title_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(locale)}" %>
      <%= f.label attr_name %>
      <%= f.text_field attr_name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your controller you'll have to `permit` the localized attribute names as well, something like:

```
def update
  # ...
  @post.update(permitted_params)
  # ...
end

# ...

private

def permitted_params
  params.require(:post).permit(I18n.available_locales.map { |l|
    :"title_#{Mobility.normalize_locale(l)}"
  })
end
```

Comment: I have created this little helper for my translation forms: https://gist.github.com/Oldharlem/f6b1e9dcc79127039c9fab744327e2c5

call like:

     translatable_html(I18n.available_locales) do |locale|
          text_field "name_#{locale}", class: 'form-control' 
     end

This will render your locales in bootstrap tabs